# Why does C not offer syntactically transparent references like C++ and Java do?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

I tried to learn more about the historical reason[s] for passing by value in C.
There is a Stack Overflow post that touches on this topic in relation to C++.
However, I'm interested in C. I imagine back when this decision was made, one could have opted to do what we call now "pass by reference". Yet, this was not the choice made. Are there optimization, multi-threading, etc., issues that come into play?

I tried to Google this, but didn't get anywhere.
Passing by value presents some guarantees in relation to the variable not being changed under the hood. Is this the only reason? I imagine back then the concept of "copying a fat object" wasn't much of an issue and passing by value incurred small overhead. As such, this might have been deemed the right choice. Is there more to this decision than this?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I do know that languages older than C used pass-by-reference (e.g. the original FORTRAN) or pass-by-name (Algol, IIRC), so this was a deliberate choice in C, not an accident or a case of the alternatives not having been invented yet.

Comment: Obviousness, I'd say: arguments were placed on the stack, so a value was copied over -- either the actual value or a pointer (reference) to the value, the latter of which would have to be resolved in order to use the value, so...

Comment: C implements both mechanisms  so the question does not make any sense. Only simple types , structs and unions can be passed by the value.

Comment: This belongs on retrocomputing.

Comment: @JL2210 That was a good answer I think. I was just about to upvote.

Comment: Emphasizing "pass by value", while technically correct, is kinda misleading, or half the truth. In C, references are held in pointers. When you pass a pointer by value, you have a reference in the function, reference to the variable which the pointer points to. So you might want to rephrase the question, such as "why does C not offer syntactically transparent references like C++ and Java do".

Comment: @P__J__: I am not sure I understand the statement "C implements both mechanisms." The C language is pass-by-value without exception. You can pass a pointer and change things inside off that pointer, but the pointer is still passed by value. Am I overlooking something?

Comment: @Dan other languages have pass by reference when there is no explicit reference object (like pointers). Since C explicitly has this, pass by reference would just become a syntactic sugar. So, pass by value is enough.

Comment: @Dan Well, you can't pass a (naked) array by value in C... Yet you can pass an array using syntax which looks very much like passing a reference to the passed array, no matter what it is called in the standard...

Comment: Passing by value and passing by reference (passing a pointer by value) are the same at the u-code level.  It may be important for the conceptual language level, yet passing basic type by value is simpler, faster.  At $10/byte circa 1970, every bit counts.

Comment: Also, it's probably useful to contemplate, how many languages (such as Java and Python) also provide only pass by value (I've also seen "pass by assignment" which might be less confusing). I think languages supporting actual pass by reference (such as C++ with `&` and C# with `ref`) might be in a minority.

Comment: This discussion has been very useful to me - thanks to all who chimed in. I hope this is not going to be labeled "opinion-based" - after all there is an answer that comes straight from Kernighan and Ritchie. Moreover, the answer is somewhat bound to be subjective since this was not a question like "why wouldn't this code snippet compile?". Thanks again.

Comment: @hyde Thanksf or the suggestion, i changed the question...

Answer (score 14):

In the words of Kernighan and Ritchie in *The C Programming Language*, 1978, clause 1.8 “Arguments — Call by Value,” page 24:

> Call by value is an asset, however, not a liability. It usually leads to more compact programs with fewer extraneous variables, because arguments can be treated as conveniently initialized local variables in the called routine. For example,…
>
> … When necessary, it is possible to arrange for a function to modify a variable in a calling routine. The caller must provide the *address* of the variable to be set (technically a *pointer* to the variable),…

Answer (score 7):

1. Passing by value is often faster than passing by reference and dereferencing a pointer every time you want to use an argument. As structures were not a part of early C, and then later required to be passed as a pointer, this was not a big problem.
2. Many old compilers didn't or couldn't optimize dereferences, and dereferencing a pointer every time you wanted to use an argument would be very slow.
3. Old computers needed micro-optimized code to run faster because the processors themselves weren't very fast.
4. It gives the programmer the freedom to choose whether they want to use a pointer or a value to access data.

All that together probably amounts to why C uses pass-by-value.

Comment: Yes the 10000 bytes struct will be very fast indeed

Comment: The answer does not make any sense. If it was the reason structs would be passed by the reference. Old machines have a very limited resources

Comment: @P__J__: Structures were not a performance problem in passing arguments by value because it was originally not allowed to pass structures as arguments. Per *The C Programming Language* by Kernighan and Ritchie, 1978, page 209, clause 14.1 “Structures and unions,” “Other operations, such as assigning from or to it or passing it as a parameter, draw an error message.”

Comment: @P__J__ Could you please review the updated answer? Note the changes to 1.

Answer (score 4):

C has always aimed to be well-performing and "close to the metal", and passing primitives (integers/pointers/floats) by references is simply suboptimal (primeval C didn't have structs, and when it did gain them, they were initially rather limited and you couldn't pass them by value or return them).

Passing by reference necessarily involves passing by an (implicitly dereferenced) pointer and if you're going to pass a pointer, you might as well pass the value directly and save the callee from having to fetch the pointer target.

Passing values directly also helps performance because you can stick to registers and skip the much slower memory.

Last but not least, it makes it easier to reason about code, because you know a callee may not change a variable you've passed to it by value.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the main reason to implement a so reduced complexity language was the environments supported on the ancient times of the C language design.  The best computer affordable in 1976 to run unix (v5, v6, v7?) was a pdp-11, which is a machine with 64Kb (on the lasts you could separate instructions and data in two different segments to double virtual address space) of virtual addresses.

Needing to run a C compiler with only 64kb of virtual space makes `pcc` (portable C compiler, the compiler from at&t unix for the pdp-11/unix) to overlay the text segment to allow space for all the code to fit.

And finally, think that those programmers had to write all that code with `ed(1)` on a printing teletype !!!! (no flat, 40' screens with a full screen editor with 100x180 caracters, colored syntax or similar effects)

Comment: *In my opinion, the main reason to implement a so reduced complexity language was the environments supported on the ancient times of the C language design.*  A lesson learned from FORTRAN, perhaps?

Comment: Probably, try to compile a unix v7 kernel in a pdp-11 with ed(1) as the only editor and the #, @, and DEL as the erase, kill and interrupt characters :)

Comment: @AndrewHenle, I don't think so, indeed the reason Java uses exclusively references to everything is to simplify syntax (and of course make the garbage collector simpler)

Answer (score 1):

C was always intended to (a) be close to the machine and (b) give you basic mechanisms that you could do more complicated things with, if you wanted to. The choice of passing by value is the right one, I think, under both criteria.

C gives you pass by value, but if you want the effect of pass by reference, you can easily do with with `&`. (On the other hand, if the language gave you pass by reference and you wanted to simulate pass by value, you'd be kinda stuck.)

Using pass by value also sidesteps all the conundrums with pass by reference, like the notorious (alleged) behavior in Fortran where if you called `f(5)` and then `f` modified its argument, you ended up changing all the other 5's in the program.